# Optimization of Program to find kth smallest element in an array (Java, Expected time complexity O(n))

Tags: java, arrays

Q: Given an array arr[] and a number K where K is smaller than size of array, the task is to find the Kth smallest element in the given array. It is given that all array elements are distinct.

I have gone through all the post related to this question but none of them helped me with the time complexity issue. I am new to coding and am having a hard time optimizing my solutions.

**Expected time complexity is O(n)**

This is my function with time complexity O(nlogn):

```
public static void smallestk(int arr[],int k)
{
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[k-1]);
}
```

The output is correct but I want to optimize my code from O(nlogn) to O(n)

Comment: I didn't check myself, but this claims to be a solution in O(n): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/

Comment: The usual approaches are QuickSelect (a variation of QuickSort -- O(n) on average, but O(n^2) worst case) and Median of Medians (a guaranteed O(n) variation on QuickSelect).  Google will give you multiple hits on those and other (not necessarily O(n)) approaches with the terms "kth smallest element".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will look into it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case to this problem is O(nlogk) and we can solve this using a max or min heap data structure. if k is small, this will be close to O(n). The idea is that we do not have to sort the entire array but to take a heap which is of the size k and always sort with in the k elements present in the heap.

1. O(n) for iterating through the array
2. O(logk) for sorting the k elements using Heap sort.

   public Integer getKthEle(Integer[] numbers, int k) {

   ```
   PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue(k, new Comparator<Integer>() {

       public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
           return b-a;
       }

       }
   );

   for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
       maxHeap.offer(numbers[i]);
   }
   // maintain the size k by adding to the queue if the next element is smaller than the head of the queue; remove from the head of the queue which is the largest element in the queue
   for(int i=k;i<numbers.length;i++) {
       if(numbers[i] < maxHeap.peek()) {
           maxHeap.offer(numbers[i]);
           maxHeap.poll();
       } 
   }


   return maxHeap.peek();
   ```

   }